# Causative - Have sb do sth

Tags: british-english, causative-verbs

I was wondering if this sentence is OK:

> I will have you happy (I will cause you to be happy)

Does it have the same meaning of

> I will make you happy

I wonder this because I came across a sentence like the One below

> I will have you laughing.

And to me, it seems to share the same meaning of

> I will.make you.laugh

Comment: 'I will have them laughing by the end of the evening' is unquestionably idiomatic. See AHD sense 8b:b. But it sounds less natural without 'padding' (eg 'by the end of the evening') and as a standalone,  'I will have you happy' sounds awful. It would probably be read as a Dickensian variant of the already Dickensian 'I would have you happy' (= 'I want to see you happy') using the 'yearn for' sense of 'will'.

Answer (score -1):

The difference seems to be that "laughing" is a verb that, by virtue of the gerund, is acting as a noun, but "happy" is an adjective.

So you can have:

> I will have you laughing.
>   I will have you running.
>   I will have you questioning.

But you cannot have:

> I will have you happy.
>   I will have you green.
>   I will have you tired.

You can see that the reverse is consistent. These work:

> I will make you happy.
>   I will make you green.
>   I will make you tired.

But these do not:

> I will make you laughing.
>   I will make you running.
>   I will make you questioning.

You can *make* someone *verb* or *adjective*, but you can't *make* someone *noun*.

Comment: I didn't focus on the fact that laughing was "acting", as a name there.  So, if I am right, I might say " I will have you sleeping but I cannot say I will have you asleep ...for instance

Comment: 'He will have them tired by the time they finish' is certainly idiomatic. As is the non-participial 'I will have them clean by tomorrow'.

Comment: As @EdwinAshworth mentioned in his comment on the main question, the first three examples (_I will have you laughing._ etc.) sounds awkward without some additional explanation.  _I will have you laughing **in no time at all**. sounds much better.  _I will have you running **when we finish your physical therapy** makes sense.  I think that _will have_ wants to have a definite time by which it will be accomplished.  That is, _I will have you [X] **by some time** or **upon reaching some milestone**.  I will have you questioning your reasons for visiting ELU by the end of this comment.